# How do I outdent by a specific amount of tabs?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a function that I can use to outdent (versus indent) a specific amount.

Here is what I have so far. This removes all tabs at the beginning of the lines. I think I need to create a dynamic pattern or use a function but I'm stuck:

```
var outdentPattern:RegExp = /([\t ]*)(.+)$/gm;

function outdent(input:String, outdentAmount:String = "\t"):String {

    var outdentedText:String = input.replace(outdentPattern, outdentAmount + "$2");
    return outdentedText;
}
```

Here is test data:

```
        <s:BorderContainer>
            <html:htmlOverride><![CDATA[
                <script>
                var test:Boolean = true;
                test = "string";
                </script>]]>
            </html:htmlOverride>
        </s:BorderContainer>
```

The test would be remove one tab, remove two tabs, etc.

Expected results at one tab would be:

```
    <s:BorderContainer>
        <html:htmlOverride><![CDATA[
            <script>
            var test:Boolean = true;
            test = "string";
            </script>]]>
        </html:htmlOverride>
    </s:BorderContainer>
```

And two tabs:

```
<s:BorderContainer>
    <html:htmlOverride><![CDATA[
        <script>
        var test:Boolean = true;
        test = "string";
        </script>]]>
    </html:htmlOverride>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

And three tabs with the inner tabs (whitespace) collapsing down:

```
<s:BorderContainer x="110" height="160" width="240" y="52">
<html:htmlOverride><![CDATA[
    <script>
    var test:Boolean = true;
    </script>
]]></html:htmlOverride>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

**Interesting note:**
The editor on SO is outdenting when you click code button when the code is already indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either construct a `RegExp` object from a template, or you could use the regular expression several times:

```
var temp:String = '^[\t ]{0,';

function outdent(input:String, amount:Number = 1):String {
    return input.replace(new RegExp(temp + amount.toString() + '}', 'gm'), '');
}
```

Or:

```
var pattern:RegExp = /^[\t ]/gm;

function outdent(input:String, amount:Number = 1):String {
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < amount; i++)
        input = input.replace(pattern, '');
    return input;
}
```

Comment: This helps. It revealed another problem. If I use the second one suggestion and specify an exact amount, for example, 2, then the lines with one tab are ignored. This isn't apparent with the test code.

Comment: If I use the first example and remove tabs one by one the code starts to collapse. This is also not apparent using the test code I provided. Either way this answers the question and I may accept it. It looks like I will have to add additional logic to optionally prevent code from collapsing. I'll also update the test code.

Comment: I've edited it to address the first concern. Not exactly sure what you mean by "collapse" though.

Comment: I've added another example above.